# Android Push Notification when App is not running

Tags: android, notifications, push

for my android app I want to inform the user when something on a server is happening, even when the App is not running. I've read some stuff about alternatives for C2DM but if I understand it right, things like polling or persistent connection only work if the App is running right?

Thanks.

Comment: You can create background running service which will start on bootup and continuously run still app is not running.

Comment: Why you don't want to use the C2DM? is just for that kind of situations... having a persistent connection is really expensive to maintain ( from the infrastucture point of view) and also the you have not to worry about service shuting down.

Comment: Right, I had worries about the min sdk to use C2DM, but turned out that this isn't a problem. Thanks for comments.

Answer (score 0):

well actually app can be "thrown off" but if things are running normal can be done with a Service = trick is there is a lower-priority "service" that is not as likely to get dumped